# OpenGL glBegin vs Vertex Buffer Arrays VBO

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to make an OpenGL game but now realize that what I've learned in school -> draw objects directly by glBegin/glEnd -> is old-school and bad. Readings on the internet I see that Vertex Buffer Objects and GLSL is the "proper" method for 3d programming.

**1)** Should I use OpenGL's glDrawArrays or glDrawElements?

**2)** For a game with many entities/grounds/objects, must the render function be many glDrawArrays():

```
foreach(entity in entities):
    glDrawArrays(entitiy->arrayFromMesh()) //Where we get an array of the mesh vertex points
```

or only one glDrawArrays() that encapsulates every entity:

```
glDrawArrays(map->arrayFromAllMeshes())
```

**3)** Does every graphics layer (such as DirectX) now standardize Vertex Buffer Objects?

Comment: Technically it's not "bad"--just old-school.  While all of my data is drawn with glDrawArrays/glDrawElements, if I just need to test something, I don't want to go to the programming overhead of generating a VBO and mapping data into it--just use immediate mode for small tests.

Comment: @IanMallett: it just depends on your definition of bad. It is more than old-shool, it is deprecated and is not even supported by opengl ES, WebGL or any decent core-profile context.

Comment: OpenGL ES 1.1 supported it (just like OpenGL 2 did) and WebGL doesn't even support client side arrays of *anything*.  I agree though, it should be avoided in modern code because it is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Should I use OpenGL's glDrawArrays or glDrawElements?

This depends on what your source data looks like. `glDrawArrays` is a little less complex, as you just have to draw a stream of vertices, but `glDrawElements` is useful in a situation where you have many vertices which are shared by several triangles. If you're just drawing sprites, then `glDrawArrays` is probably the simplest, but `glDrawElements` is useful for huge complex meshes where you want to save buffer space.

> 2) For a game with many entities/grounds/objects, must the render function be many glDrawArrays() or only one glDrawArrays() that encapsulates every entity:

Again this is somewhat optional, but note that you can't change program state in the middle of a drawarrays call. So that means that any two objects which need different state (different textures, different shaders, different blend settings), must have a separate draw call. However it can sometimes be helpful for performance to group as many **similar** things into a single draw call as you can.

> 3) Does every graphics layer (such as DirectX) now standardize Vertex Buffer Objects?

DirectX does have a similar concept, yes.

Comment: I think the [post-transform cache](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Post_Transform_Cache) typically only gets hit by indexed-rendering, so using `drawElements` vs `drawArrays` is not only a space improvement but will also likely increase performance.